# How to Order By "SUM" in Eloquent Query Builder (Laravel 4)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table that has a relationship for artists that have been "liked".  I.e. something like this:

```
artists_id   fan_id  
1            1
1            2
1            3
4            1
4            2
```

There are tables "artists" and "fans" that contain the info for those entities.  I would like to order the results of a query by the sum of the users that have liked an artist in Eloquent query builder in Laravel 4 (i.e. grouping results by count and then ordering them by count desc).  And I would like to pull the artist information.

This is what I have:

```
$artists_most_popular = DB::table('artists')
                        ->join('fanartists', 'artists.id', '=', 'fanartists.artist_id')
                        ->orderBy('sum('fanartists.fan_id')')
                        ->groupBy('artists.id')
                        ->take(50)
                        ->get();

        return $artists_most_popular;
```

I know this isn't right, but I'm at a loss as to how to structure this in eloquent.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `DB::raw` in the `orderBy`. So your example would be...

```
$artists_most_popular = DB::table('artists')
                    ->join('fanartists', 'artists.id', '=', 'fanartists.artist_id')
                    ->orderBy(DB::raw('sum(\'fanartists.fan_id\')'))
                    ->groupBy('artists.id')
                    ->take(50)
                    ->get();

return $artists_most_popular;
```

Comment: I get the error : syntax error, unexpected 'fanartists' (T_STRING)

Comment: That was actually an error in your code. I have edited it to fix it.